# What is the force exreted by gas particles per unit area on the walls of the container?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, statistical-mechanics, gas

It must not be pressure because it is a energy.

Comment: The pressure exerted by an ideal gas on its container walls is proportional to the total (kinetic) energy of the molecules. There's nothing contradictory here.

Answer (score 1):

It's pressure. That's what pressure is - it's the definition of pressure. Force, energy, and pressure are different things. They even have different units. You can't say "my room is 12 hours long." The same way you cant say "the force per unit area is an energy."